# Can the phone storage device of an android phone be shown when connected to Lubuntu?

Tags: disk-usage, android, parted

My Android phone has 1GB Phone space, and 2GB MicroSD card.

When I connect the phone to my computer (Ubuntu) via a USB cable, only the 2GB MicroSD card is shown in `sudo parted -l` and `df -l` commands. Is the 1GB Phone space not possible to be shown?

Thanks.

Comment: No, not in that way. You should install `adb` on your lubuntu system, turn on usb debugging in your android phone, connect to the phone with `adb shell`, and then from within the android system issue `cat /proc/partitions`, `ls /sys/block`, etc.

Comment: Some versions of android let a computer connected via usb access the sd card *directly* by unmounting all the partitions, and not letting any program running in android access it in any way. In that case, the sd card appear to the connected pc just as if it were in a card reader, and you can examine its partition table, etc. How could android do the same with its internal flash memory, where its own OS and apps are stored? ;-)

Comment: Do you mean the phone's own storage is not shown in Ubuntu, because it stores OS and apps that are running?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to access the phone's own storage, you should use `MTP` or `adb` instead of "USB Mass storage". `MTP` is flaky and has some serious bugs (mentioned in the answer below). `adb` has it's own share of idiocy (`adb push` will create files with 666 perms, for instance).

Comment: @pizdelect Question mentioned 1GB, that is more likely to be an stanalone filesystem implemented internally used an "not-removeable" sd-card. But Phone still allow you to use extra "removeale" sd-card. Both are seen as External Storage by Android API. Not showing on connection might just be a bug or non-exist feature. Not all Android Phones are Nexus-like.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克  the internal, emulated sd-card is a compatibility fiction on android -- there isn't even a separate partition backing it. And my huawei u8350 (froyo) which I'm still using (because I hate typing on a touchscreen) has just 512m of internal flash memory ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a known bug with the following workaround:

1. Safely remove your connected device in Ubuntu.
2. Turn off the device. Remove the SD card from the device.
3. Turn on the device without the SD card.
4. Turn off the device again.
5. Put the SD card back in and turn on the device again.

Source: [DebugPoint.com](https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/03/how-to-access-android-devices-internal-storage-and-sd-card-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-using-media-transfer-protocol-mtp/) and [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/11d21gbWyQo)

You may also find this page helpful: http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-android-sd-card-ubuntu/